# How can I bake this "filled pretzel"?

Tags: baking, oven, frozen

(This is a follow-up of [this question](/questions/107424).)

I'm trying to bake a "[frozen, stuffed pretzel](https://www.hotpockets.com/en/products/lean-pockets/chicken-broccoli-and-cheddar-pretzel-bread)". (Why? See previous question.) My first attempt (350°F for 35 minutes), however, was less than satisfactory; the filling seemed okay, but the pretzel shell did not cook through. I suspect that the frozen filling is the culprit?

Given how the previous attempt turned out, what would be a better way to try cooking these? Specifically, in what way(s) could I modify my approach so that the shell cooks evenly and all the way through?

Comment: I'd call this 'enough time wasted trying to get junk food to be edible' ;-)))

Comment: @Tetsujin, amusing, but it would take me much more time, not to mention cost more, to try to prepare something of similar adequacy as a meal. They really aren't bad if they're cooked properly. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out what constitutes "properly" yet.

Comment: So... I think I've decided that the 'pretzel crust' variety simply cannot be cooked reasonably, period.

Comment: & your food appreciation quotient has just gone up 3 points ;-)